# Сериализация класса в query string

Tags: java, строки, url, сериализация, lombok

Есть задача сериализации кастомного класса в query string (параметры в URL строке). Какие-то поля класса должны быть обязательно, какие-то не обязательно. Например:

```java
public class UserQueryParameters {
    String name; // *
    int age; // Не обязательно
    String sex; // Не обязательно
}
```

Надо как-то объявить, какие поля сериализовать (в реалиях java это маршаллинг называется, вроде), какие нет, а затем преобразовывать получившуюся структуру в строку вида

```
name=John&age=23
```

Как это можно реализовать?

---

Пробовал с использованием `lombok` аннотаций:

```java
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@Builder
public class UserQueryParameters {
    String name; // *
    int age; // Не обязательно
    String sex; // Не обязательно
}
```

Далее через билдер формирование инстанса класса с заполненными полями:

```java
UserQueryParameters params = UserQueryParameters.builder()
        .name("John")
        .sex("m")
        .build();
```

И формирование query string путём рефлексии:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

// ...

for (Field field : params.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (field.get(params) != null) {
        addToQueryString(field.get(params));
    }
}
```

Но, очевидно, такое решение не подходит, т.к. для `int` поля, например, будет не `null`, а `0`.

Comment: Придумалось использовать `Integer` вместо `int`, но это больше походит на костыль, а не на решение.

Comment: Не понятно почему Integer костыль. В полне нормальное решение. А так на самом деле сделать нужно по другому

Comment: @AzizUmarov Костыль, на мой взгляд, само решение с использованием `lombok`, т.к. нет никакого контроля, объявлено ли обязательное поле или нет.

Comment: А ломбок сам это не костыль. Это просто класс допишется по стандарту не вами.

Comment: Я подозреваю, вас интересует [UriComponentsBuilder](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-uricomponentsbuilder/) из Spring. Если он для ваших целей оверкилл, то и ломбок вам не нужен. Достаточно кастомных аннотаций на поля и простого сериализатора. Если интересно, могу накидать заготовку.

Comment: @PakUula На спринговый натыкался, но тащить такой тяжёлый фреймворк ради такой задачи действительно избыточно. С кастомными аннотациями думал, но, т.к. жаву начал изучать относительно недавно, до чего-то путного сам додуматься не смог. Буду благодарен, если набросаете прототип.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, ваш вопрос содержит половину ответа :)

> Надо как-то объявить, какие поля сериализовать (в реалиях java это маршаллинг называется, вроде), какие нет

Для этого в java используется механизм аннотаций. Вам нужно создать собственные аннотации, пометить ими поля в классах, и затем в маршаллере пройтись reflection-ом по полям объекта класса, выбрать из них помеченные аннотацией, и сгенерировать из помеченных полей пары `key=value` для запроса.

Я сделал простенький пример. Создал аннотацию `QueryField` с двумя параметрами

- `required` определяет, обязательное поле или нет. По умолчанию `true` - это сделано для того, чтобы явным образом обозначать необязательные поля.
- `name` задаёт, какое имя использовать при сериализации. Если не задано, то используется имя поля.

Вот пример, как пользоваться аннотацией. Класс с полями `age`, `name` и `sex`. Обязательно только поле `name`, поле `sex` сериализуется как  `gender`.

```java
    public static class TestData {
        @QueryField
        public String name; // *
        @QueryField(required = false)
        public Integer age; // Не обязательно
        @QueryField(name = "gender", required = false)
        public String sex; // Не обязательно
    }
```

Аннотация в java определяется ключевым словом `@interface`:

```java
package org.example.query;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

// Keep annotation in generated byte code
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
// Compiler hint: the annotation should be applied to fields only
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface QueryField {
    // Custom field name in the generated query string
    public String name() default "";
    // If `true` the field value must be non-null 
    public boolean required() default true;
}
```

(подробнее в [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6))

Теперь можно было бы перейти к написанию сериализатора, но, как поклонник Test Driven Development, я начну с [теста](https://pastebin.com/qm5ZZMu9). Он великоват для вставки сюда, поэтому я выложил его в pastebin.

Поясню лишь идею теста.

1. Подготовить данные.
2. Сгенерировать строку.
3. Так как порядок полей в строке, вообще говоря, не определён, то вместо сравнения с эталонной строкой лучше строку разобрать и сложить значения в контейнер.
4. Потом в тесте проверить, какие именно значения обнаружились в контейнере.
5. Заодно проверить, что ничего лишего там не завелось.

```java
    // Тест для сериализатора с одним отсуствующим необязательным полем.
    @Test
    void test_serialize() throws SerializerException {
        TestData sample = new TestData();
        sample.age = 23;
        sample.name = "John";
        
        String actual = Serializer.buildQuery(sample);
        
        Map<String, String> data = parseQuery(actual);
        
        assertTrue(data.containsKey("age"));
        assertTrue(data.containsKey("name"));
        // Проверяем, что других полей нет.
        assertEquals(2, data.keySet().size());
        
        assertEquals("John", data.get("name"));
        assertEquals("23", data.get("age"));
        
    }
```

Теперь, когда тест готов, можно написать [простенький сериализатор](https://pastebin.com/y1GfS0bC) для иллюстрации идеи.

Там всё просто. Сначала перебираем поля объекта и ищем поля с аннотацией `QueryField`. Если такое поле найдено, пытаемся извлечь поле. В ответ JRE может выкинуть исключения - обрабатываем.

Затем проверяем, вдруг поле пустое и одновременно необязательное. Такие поля пропускаем. Про пустое обязательное поле кидаем исключение.

Затем конвертируем значение в строку (на всяк пожарный все опасные символы экранируем) и подбираем имя - либо заданное в аннотации, либо полученное из имени поля. Добавляем пару "name=valueText" в строку результата. Профит!

```java
    public static String buildQuery(Object obj) throws SerializerException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (java.lang.reflect.Field fld : obj.getClass().getFields()) {
            QueryField annot = fld.getAnnotation(QueryField.class);
            if (annot == null) {
                // This field has no "QueryField" annotation, ignore it.
                continue;
            }
            
            Object fldVal;
            try {
                fldVal = fld.get(obj);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Should never happen", e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new SerializerException("Failed to access field "+fld.getName(), e);
            }
            
            if (fldVal == null) {
                if (annot.required()) {
                    throw new SerializerException("Required field is null");
                } else {
                    // Ignore optional fields
                    continue;
                }
            }
            
            String valText = urlEncode(fldVal.toString());
            
            String valName = annot.name();
            if (valName.length() == 0) {
                // No custom name, use field name instead
                valName = fld.getName();
            }
            valName = urlEncode(valName); 
            
            result.append('&').append(valName).append('=').append(valText);
        }
        return result.substring(1);
    }
```

Как-то так оно делается.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вы обрабатываете строковый запрос. Я бы сделал сначала сериализацию в промежуточный класс со строковыми полями. Чтобы не получить необработанную ошибку на конвертации.

```
public class ResuestUserQueryParameters {
    String name; 
    String age; 
    String sex; 
}
```

А уже далее обрабатывал его, проверка на реквайред и прочие значения.

А поскольку обычно сами реквесты уже по умолчанию сделают это за вас. (распарсят запрос на строки). Вам по сути нужно самому проверить и обработать параметры